# Teamcity Rest API: Get only builds with artifacts available

Tags: c#, teamcity

I'm building an inhouse tool to download builds from TeamCity, however the JSON I retrieve from TeamCity is returning builds that dont have artifacts. Is there a parameter or filter I can add to the WebRequest string to filter out the builds without an Artifact available?